# Updating observableArray in a computedObservable creates a circular reference?

Tags: knockout.js

I have created a View Model object for use with KnockoutJS.

It has a property called 'Years' which is an observable array...

```
viewModel.Years = ko.observableArray([]);
```

I then have a computed observable, in which I want to update the contents of the array...

```
viewModel.FuturePrediction = ko.computed(function () {
    viewModel.Years.removeAll();

    // etc...
});
```

The problem I'm having is that this appears to create an infinite loop. I'm *guessing* that Knockout is detecting that I'm accessing the 'Years' property and creating a dependency between it and the 'FuturePrediction' property.

As soon as I attempt to modify the contents of the array, the computed function gets triggered again. The problem is that all I'm doing is updating the 'Years' array, not reading it - and therefore there *isn't actually a dependency*.

Any ideas what I can do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In KO 2.1, computed observables cannot trigger themselves, so you would be in better shape with 2.1.

Calling the array manipulation methods do read and set the array, so it would create a dependency.  You could do `viewModel.Years([]);` as long as you are not depending on the original underlying array for anything (have references to it elsewhere).

I am not sure about your full scenario, but an option would be to build up your "new" array and then finally set the result as the value of `Years` rather than clearing it first.

Like:

```
viewModel.FuturePrediction = ko.computed(function () {
    var result = [];
    //add things to result

    viewModel.Years(result);
});
```

Again, I am not sure about your exact scenario, but if the end goal is to create a new array based on some criteria, then you could have `FuturePrediction` be the array and return it as the result of the computed observable.  Just not sure about your situation exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually just came back here to say that I found the answer on your blog here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/knockout-2-dot-1-is-out.html - namely - upgrading to KO 2.1! Thanks again, and keep up the good work! :o)